# jQuery Selectbox .change only firing once

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple select box, on change it does a simple multiplacation problem and displays the results.

Problem is once you select every option within the list, it does not work when clicking the same option twice.

```
$('select#price-list').change(function () {
    var length = $(this).find('option:selected').data("length");
    var price = $(this).find('option:selected').data("price");
    var total = price * length;
    $('#price-shared').html(price);
    $('#price-shared-total').html(total);
});



$(function () {
    $("#price-list").selectbox();
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/xc39V/

Found the issue: Turns out it was within the plugin itself,

Changed:

```
$(target).find("option[value='" + value + "']").attr("selected", TRUE);
```

To:

```
$(target).find("option[value='" + value + "']").prop("selected", TRUE);
```

Comment: Can you please give an example? If I select same option twice from the menu so lets say Pay per month then if you select again, it shws problems?

Comment: Why would you expect a different output when you click the same thing twice?

Comment: If you go thru the box options and click every option once, its ok, but then if you go back and select a different option it doesn't change. It only changes once.

Comment: what is exactly the problem i dont get it !!

Comment: Start from option 1, click it. go to the next click it, right to the last option. Now go back to the first option... it doesn't change.

Comment: why would you need to select the same option twice when it does the same job? From UI point of views since your select box is customized I would suggest to disable the selected option.

Comment: If a user decides one option the changes their mind, thus the need to be able to go back and re-calculate!

Comment: From the comments on my answer below, I think it's important that the problem only is in Firefox.

Comment: Your right! Does anyone know a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure that the change event is not fired, if you don't actually change the selection in the select box. If you hook up the functionality to the click event instead it should work. 
So if you change it to:

```
$('select#price-list').click(function () {...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Really?
That's wierd - it's working in the fiddle you linked to.
What do result are you expecting when choosing the same option twice?

Comment: If I click every option once thru it works, but when you go back and select a different option it does not change.

Comment: So if you select "Pay per month", then "6 month package" and the "pay per month" again it does not work? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes exactly, if you click every option then start all over its not changing, its only changes once. Firefox 18.0.1

Comment: Hmmm..you're right. In Firefox it is not working - I was testing in Chrome and that works fine. Not sure why Firefox is acting up.

Comment: ohh now I see what u mean by not working in firefox. By inspecting element on the selectbox I can tell that when you select every of them till the last one you will eventually see all of the attribute is being set "selected". So the best solving issue is to remove the previous "selected" option. <<== should be good hint, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you are using the wrong event! Change is meant to fire only when the value of the select is CHANGING. So if you wish to have the event fired each time the user selects anything (even the same value) from the select use the click event!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#price-list').on('change click',function () {
    var length = $(this).find('option:selected').data("length");
    var price = $(this).find('option:selected').data("price");
    var total = price * length;
    $('#price-shared').html(price);
    $('#price-shared-total').html(total);
});



$(function () {
    $("#price-list").selectbox();
});
```

This should work !